# Can I download files from a folder with a Password?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

t get a password to enter,this folder get a password (of course i insert the password ) because its  deny  access and to be canceled from person without permission so i'm looking how download files from that folder with C# .
Before i tried to download files but Visual Studio got an error: "Access Denied"!
Do you have any advice how download files from a Folder with Password or its impossible?
Thanks a lot!

Nice Regards.

EDIT : Here is the code snippet that i use to download the files from a folder

```
  private List<string> GetFolder(string Folder)
    {

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.mp3",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        List<string> str = new List<string>();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            str.Add(file.FullName);


        }
        return  str;

    }

 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
GetFolder(@"D:\\Music\\")
}
```

Sorry i forget to add the code before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're downloading files using a URL, you can specify the username and password in the URL: `http://user:pass@host/path`

Obviously, if your username or (more likely) password has funny characters, these need to be %XX encoded appropriately.

Comment: Hi Chris ,thanks to reply me ,
in my case i should put on Load Method : GetFolder(pass,@"D:\\Music\\") or i wrong?
Thanks